# Is safe to put variables in a onclick definition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a really newbie question.

I've managed to get some jQuery stuff running quite smootly but i ended up having many
events like this one..

```
<div class="aClass" id="B436" onclick="updateSearch('B436', '','Brand','193557', 0)">My Name</div>
```

Now i'm wondering if it's "safe" to put all my necessary function variables in this way. I check everything in the function so even if with firebug someone change some values they can't hurt much but... is this the correct way to do ?

Thanks

Comment: You have server side validation right?

Comment: Sure, everything that goes touching the database is cleaned in php later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely safe. However, it's not considered very good practice to put handlers in `onclick` or any other attribute of an element, *especially* considering you have jQuery. You should do it using `.click()` instead:

```
$('#B436').click(function() {
    updateSearch('B436', '', 'Brand', '193557', 0);
});
```

for example.

If, however, anything of any remote security concern can be done using JavaScript, it probably shouldn't be done in JavaScript.

Comment: this would need to consider variables though, so if the params were passed as data attributes he may extract those with jquery... assuming the click would be more appropriately on aClass so he doesnt need to write out a ton of click listeners

Comment: I may not be able to always use the listener. As most values like 'B436' '193557' are generated by php dynamically

Comment: mmm... what about something like this..

'<div class="aClass" id="B436##Brand#193557">My Name</div>'

Then in JS file

'$('.aClass').click(function() {
    // Get the id of the item that fired
    // split in a array by #
    // call updateSearch
    updateSearch(value[0], value[1], value[2], value[3], value[4]);
});'

can this be considered a better way to handle ?
Why the word _especially_ ? Can you spend two word on this to explain me ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a matter of safety per se, but more of a readability issue.

When you keep your webpage components isolated from one another (stylesheets in a CSS file, JavaScript in a JS file, and HTML in its own file), you are less prone to losing code in your wall of text.

I personally find it easier to use jQuery to attach the handler, as I don't have to worry about messing with HTML attributes.

But then again, unreadable code is prone to breaking.

Comment: Sure, but i need php to place all my variables in the HTML code. All JQ functions are in a separate file

Answer (score 0):

It's one way to do it. The only way it could be unsafe is if you were using the variables foolishly - like ajaxing your database directly without purifying the variables or something.

It also depends on what you call safe. Anyone can run firebug and mess with any site, but it will only be for them. It's not like changing the dom with firebug is considered a bug or anything and it's certainly not "hacking" since you stand to gain nothing from doing so.

Comment: Every variable i pass throught the db is cleaned with php, the only ones that are not cleand just change some css in the html

Answer (score 0):

If you want safety in this case, You **must** have server side validation.

It doesn't matter if you use jQuery or not.

Comment: Every variable i pass throught the db is cleaned with php, the only ones that are not cleand just change some css in the html